# Checking Transaction Success on Ethereum Testnet (Remix)

Tags: ethereum, remix

I've successfully deployed a smart contract for a garbage token on ERC20 testnet (Ropstein).  I would like to confirm that send/receive is working by using a second address and I'd much prefer to do this without setting up another Metamask or wallet.  Is there a place or way I can simply generate an address and check receipt without setting up any real wallet anywhere?  (I.e., a temporary address generator?)

Yes I've done it in the JS VMs and I'm being stupid paranoid.  But I'd really like to confirm with two actual (or at least off-remix, non-virtual) addresses.  (And yes I did Google, although I would be happy to have my search skills proven inferior.)

Comment: May i ask that if its working correctly in the test environment, why do you need to double check?. Also what do you mean by two actual addresses?.

Comment: As noted it is just my paranoia that somehow the JS test environment is not 100% simulating the "real" environment.  And "actual" I guess means nothing, but perhaps I meant addresses wherein I could check the fund values and that were not generated by the test enviro.

Comment: I understand. Well its not the actual answer. Maybe someone else can help you on this. But i can suggest you using a Ethereum client like parity or ganache (Truffle). Maybe you already know, truffle is easy to work with. It already provides good functionality to write, test, deploy and then call the contract functions. And if everything works correctly there, you can relax. It is still a test environment though and thats the purpose of it to test code before you actually deploy in real. But then again, you will have to deal with wallet management and probably Metamask again to work with :(

Comment: You're right I should be doing things on Truffle.